# One to many relationship with EF 4.1 Code First - Database using Instead of Triggers

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, one-to-many

We are working on EF code first to evaluate if it fits to our existing database. The structure of the database entites are

1) Product (Composite Key)

int Product ID: PK  (Non Identity)- Autogenerated in Instead Of Trigger
   int Version From: PK  (Non Identity)- Autogenerated in Instead Of Trigger

2) Pack (Composite Key)

PackID : PK (Non Identity)- Autogenerated in Instead Of Trigger
   Version From: PK (Non Identity)- Autogenerated in Instead Of Trigger
   Product ID: (Cannot be set as FK - Design Constraint)

RelationShip: Product has many packs

How can we model the above scenario with EF Code First 4.1?

---

The solution which tried

```
public class Product
{
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public short Version { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Pack> Packs { get; set; }
}

public class Pack
{
        public int PackID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public short Version { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Pack> Pack { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pack>().ToTable("Pack");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                    .HasKey(a => new { a.ProductID, a.VersionFrom });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pack>()
                    .HasKey(a => new { a.PackID, a.VersionFrom });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<Pack>(x => x.Packs).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductID);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

....

var product = new Product { ProductName = "EntTest1"};
var pack = new Pack {};


            using (var productContext = new ProductContext())
            {

                product.Packs.Add(pack);
                productContext.Product.Add(product);
                productContext.SaveChanges(); //**ERROR**
            }
```

....

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : Number of Properties in the Dependent and Principal Role in a relationship constraint must be exactly identical.
```

Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Pack` class need two foreign key scalar properties

```
public class Pack
{
        public int PackID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public short ProductVersion { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

You need to supply both scalar properties to the mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
.HasMany<Pack>(x => x.Packs).WithRequired(p => p.Product)
.HasForeignKey(p => new { p.ProductID, p.ProductVersion});
```

**Edit:** Without mapping scalar properties

```
public class Pack
{
        public int PackID { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
.HasMany<Pack>(x => x.Packs).WithRequired(p => p.Product)
.Map(m => m.MapKey("ProductID", "ProductVersion"));
```

Your `Pack(s)` table should have `ProductID`, `ProductVersion` columns with matching data types.

Comment: Is there any possibility to  create a relation without  providing  scalar properties.